# Buttons stop working after adding Html Editor Extender to the page

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, ajaxcontroltoolkit, htmleditorextender

I have a working web form, when I add Html Editor Extender to the page, all the buttons in that page stop working. When I remove the Html Editor extender , the page works fine.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"
                    Height="300px" Width="600px">
                </asp:TextBox>
                <asp:HtmlEditorExtender ID="HtmlEditorExtender1" runat="server" EnableSanitization="False"
                    DisplaySourceTab="True" TargetControlID="TextBox1">
                </asp:HtmlEditorExtender>
```

Comment: aha.. ehm.. that can be possible.. can you post your Html/javascript Code? it will help us to help you :)

Comment: This is in my form, but it inherits from a master page. <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#form1").attr("class", "form-inline");
        });
    </script>
</asp:Content>

Comment: This is in my master page

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem.  Take out the  DisplaySourceTab="true", this should solve the problem.